# Parse a date from the url in php/wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, parsing, url

I have a URL which includes a date in format yyyy-mm-dd, How can I parse the URL to get the date in PHP?

URL example: http://example.com/nepal/events/visit-nepal-2020/2020-01-09

Comment: Is the date always the last element in the URL? If not, can there be multiple dates in an URL? How would you handle this?

Comment: @MultiSuperFreek Yes there will be a single date at the last part of the url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to get last value of date from the URL so check below the code

```
$str = 'http://example.com/nepal/events/visit-nepal-2020/2020-01-09';
$id = substr($str, strrpos($str, '/') + 1);
$date = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($id));
echo $date;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regular expression on `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`. This will get you the first date in YYYY-MM-DD format occurring in the request URI:

```
preg_match('/\/(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})[\/]?/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $match);
$date = ($match) ? $match[1] : null;
```

If no date is found, `$date` will contain `null`;